# kohana 3.3 ORM_Validation_Exception [ 0 ]: Failed to validate array

Tags: php, kohana

I have a problem with login.

My Model_User:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User
{
    public function login_user($data)
    {
         if(isset($data['loginSubmit'])
         {
              $auth = Auth::instance()->login($data['loginUsername'], $data['loginPassword']);
              return $auth;
         }
    }

    public function rules()
    {
         return array(
             'username' => array(
                   array('not_empty'),
                   array('min_length', array(':value', 3)),
                   array('max_length', array(':value', 32)),
                   array(array($this, 'unique'), array('username', ':value')),
             ),
             'password' => array(
                   array('not_empty'),
                   array('min_length', array(':value', 8)),
                   array('max_length', array(':value', 32)), //here is a bug
             ),
             'email' => array(
                   array('not_empty'),
                   array('min_length', array(':value', 4)),
                   array('max_length', array(':value', 128)),
                   array('email'),
                   array(array($this, 'unique'), array('email', ':value')),
             ),
         );
    }
}
```

In a DB, password has a 64 signs (hash). Validating is positive, but sth is wrong. I know, that is caused by difference in password length - raw password has max 32 signs, but after hashing password has max 64 signs. And when I'm calling

```
Auth::instance()->login($data['loginUsername'], $data['loginPassword']);
```

Validating rules are called second time, but after hashing, what causes errors. How I can fix it?

Comment: Set the `max_length` rule for `password` to 64 chars

Comment: Yep, I know. But I want to have max_length 32.

Comment: You seem to mix things up. `rules()` defines the rules for database storage, not for your input field. you need to allow 64 chars to be able to save the hash to the database

Comment: Ok. But I heard that in Kohana 3.3, at first, validating is called, not filters (hashing).

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Do you still get an error if you set `max_length` to 64? If not it's likely that the filters run first

Comment: 64 solved problem. But still it is not what I want xD

Comment: Why would you limit a user in a way so his account is less secure (shorter password)? Since you hash it to 64 chars, why even bother checking the raw length?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. I only want to understand, why password with max_length less than size in DB is invalid :) In a future maybe it will be helpful^^